# I have a dataset. It has maximum peaks that I would like to eliminate. How do I do that?

Tags: sql, sql-server

Attached below is a sample of the data.

```
CTIME   WEIGHT
7/23/2016 22:49 97.94
7/23/2016 22:48 97.95
7/23/2016 22:48 97.95
7/23/2016 22:48 97.96
7/23/2016 22:48 97.96
7/23/2016 22:48 97.94
7/23/2016 22:48 97.94
7/23/2016 22:48 97.95
7/23/2016 22:48 97.95
7/23/2016 22:48 98
7/23/2016 22:48 98
7/23/2016 22:48 98
7/23/2016 22:48 98
7/23/2016 22:48 98.01
7/23/2016 22:48 98.01
7/23/2016 22:48 97.95
7/23/2016 22:48 97.95
7/23/2016 22:48 98
7/23/2016 22:48 98
7/23/2016 22:48 97.94
7/23/2016 22:48 97.94
7/23/2016 22:47 97.95
7/23/2016 22:47 97.95
7/23/2016 22:47 97.96
7/23/2016 22:47 97.96
7/23/2016 22:47 97.95
7/23/2016 22:47 97.95
7/23/2016 22:47 97.99
7/23/2016 22:47 97.99
7/23/2016 22:47 98.03
7/23/2016 22:47 97.88
7/23/2016 22:47 97.88
7/23/2016 22:47 97.88
7/23/2016 22:47 97.3
7/23/2016 22:47 95.53
7/23/2016 22:47 95.53
7/23/2016 22:47 95.58
7/23/2016 22:47 95.58
7/23/2016 22:47 95.57
7/23/2016 22:47 95.57
7/23/2016 22:47 95.51
7/23/2016 22:46 95.51
7/23/2016 22:46 95.52
7/23/2016 22:46 95.52
7/23/2016 22:46 95.52
7/23/2016 22:46 95.52
7/23/2016 22:46 95.55
7/23/2016 22:46 95.55
7/23/2016 22:46 95.53
7/23/2016 22:46 95.53
7/23/2016 22:46 95.52
7/23/2016 22:46 95.52
7/23/2016 22:46 95.54
7/23/2016 22:46 95.54
7/23/2016 22:46 95.5
7/23/2016 22:46 95.5
7/23/2016 22:46 95.51
7/23/2016 22:46 95.51
7/23/2016 22:46 95.48
7/23/2016 22:46 95.48
7/23/2016 22:46 95.52
7/23/2016 22:45 95.52
7/23/2016 22:45 95.53
7/23/2016 22:45 95.44
7/23/2016 22:45 95.44
7/23/2016 22:45 95.44
7/23/2016 22:45 95.43
7/23/2016 22:45 95.4
7/23/2016 22:45 95.4
7/23/2016 22:45 95.41
7/23/2016 22:45 95.41
7/23/2016 22:45 95.39
7/23/2016 22:45 95.39
7/23/2016 22:45 95.41
7/23/2016 22:45 95.41
7/23/2016 22:45 94.84
7/23/2016 22:45 94.84
7/23/2016 22:45 94.84
7/23/2016 22:45 93.89
7/23/2016 22:45 71.53
7/23/2016 22:45 71.53
7/23/2016 22:44 43.65
7/23/2016 22:44 43.65
7/23/2016 22:44 4.46
7/23/2016 22:44 4.46
7/23/2016 22:44 0.34
7/23/2016 22:44 0.34
7/23/2016 22:44 0.34
7/23/2016 22:44 0.34
7/23/2016 22:44 0.36
7/23/2016 22:44 0.36
7/23/2016 22:44 0.41
7/23/2016 22:44 0.41
7/23/2016 22:44 0.42
7/23/2016 22:44 0.42
7/23/2016 22:44 0.39
7/23/2016 22:44 0.39
7/23/2016 22:44 0.4
7/23/2016 22:44 0.41
7/23/2016 22:44 0.41
7/23/2016 22:44 0.41
7/23/2016 22:43 0.4
7/23/2016 22:43 0.41
7/23/2016 22:43 0.41
7/23/2016 22:43 0.41
7/23/2016 22:43 0.41
7/23/2016 22:43 0.41
7/23/2016 22:43 0.41
7/23/2016 22:43 0.47
7/23/2016 22:43 0.47
7/23/2016 22:43 0.47
7/23/2016 22:43 0.47
7/23/2016 22:43 0.47
7/23/2016 22:43 0.47
7/23/2016 22:43 0.47
7/23/2016 22:43 0.47
7/23/2016 22:43 0.49
7/23/2016 22:43 0.49
7/23/2016 22:43 0.48
7/23/2016 22:43 0.48
7/23/2016 22:43 0.49
7/23/2016 22:42 0.49
7/23/2016 22:42 0.49
7/23/2016 22:42 0.49
7/23/2016 22:42 0.48
7/23/2016 22:42 0.48
7/23/2016 22:42 0.5
7/23/2016 22:42 0.5
7/23/2016 22:42 0.51
7/23/2016 22:42 0.51
7/23/2016 22:42 0.54
7/23/2016 22:42 14.24
7/23/2016 22:42 14.24
7/23/2016 22:42 14.24
7/23/2016 22:42 105.86
7/23/2016 22:42 183.02
7/23/2016 22:42 183.02
7/23/2016 22:42 207.56
7/23/2016 22:42 207.56
7/23/2016 22:42 197.45
7/23/2016 22:42 197.45
7/23/2016 22:41 194.33
7/23/2016 22:41 194.33
7/23/2016 22:41 194.31
7/23/2016 22:41 194.31
7/23/2016 22:41 194.31
7/23/2016 22:41 194.31
7/23/2016 22:41 194.31
7/23/2016 22:41 194.31
```

If you see, a couple of rows (sometimes the number of rows are more, sometime its less) contain a value of 207. The value that I would like to capture is 194.
The data is stored in a SQL database (2005) and I would like to get the value of 194 via sql queries.

Is there any way to do this?

Comment: Oops, It looks horrible and unreadable. I had pasted it from an excel sheet. Is there a better way (must be...)

Comment: Hmmm, `select * from yourtable where weight like '% 194%'`?

Comment: No. The above is just one sample. The values keep on changing. The data comes via a program that reads the RS232 port or a weigh bridge. Many times, the weigh is less than 100, but due to some or the other physical movement, these peaks occur, which do not represent the actual weight.

Answer (score 0):

You should find how much the current weight is "far" in value from the mesures of weight that are near in time.

The following SQL code could be a solution:

```
SELECT [MEASURE_ID], CTIME, [WEIGHT], avg([NEAR_TIME_WEIGHT]) [AVERAGE_WEIGHT]
 FROM
 (
  SELECT a.*, b.[WEIGHT] [NEAR_TIME_WEIGHT]
   FROM CTIME_WEIGHT a
   INNER JOIN CTIME_WEIGHT b
    ON a.[MEASURE_ID]>b.[MEASURE_ID]-8
     AND a.[MEASURE_ID]<b.[MEASURE_ID]+8
 ) sbt
 GROUP BY [MEASURE_ID], CTIME, [WEIGHT]
 HAVING [WEIGHT]*0.99<avg([NEAR_TIME_WEIGHT])
  AND [WEIGHT]*1.01>avg([NEAR_TIME_WEIGHT])
 ORDER BY [MEASURE_ID]
```

You have to copy your data in a three column table (I named it CTIME_WEIGHT). The table must have a row number ordered following the sampling time (I named this field [MEASURE_ID]).

My solution takes 8 values before and 8 values after the current measure and makes their average; if the current value is too low (less than 99%) or too high (more than 101%) respect the average value, it is discarded.